navigate back and forth in P4V
As an example. When I use modern IDE's there is a way to navigate between the files. I can navigate to the next tab or I can navigate to the position where I was before. This makes it easy to work in several different files which are spread among the project.
I'm looking for the same solution in P4V. Let's say I started in main stream, then went to my first feature locked at a specific file and went to a history entry and then maybe to the Depot tree.
Now I want to get back to the start. I want to hit a shortcut several times until I'm back to main.
Is there an option out there?

I think this is something you'd have to file an enhancement request for.
